Equivalence of nowhere dense set
I want to ask a question from this solution:
I have understood how do this solution work almost every part. But I’m confused that in the end, why $D\subseteq (X\setminus A)^\circ$ can imply $D\subseteq (X\setminus A)^\circ$ is dense in $X$ ? Which property should I apply? Hope everyone can give some explanation, thanks a lot!

If $D \subseteq D_1$ and $D$ is dense in $X$ , then $D_1$ is dense in $X$:  $X= \overline D \subseteq \overline D_1\subseteq X$ so $\overline D_1\subseteq X$. Take $D_1=(X\setminus A)^{0}$.

Why $X \subseteq \overline D_1$ and $\overline D_1 \subseteq \overline D$ ? I think that $D \subseteq D_1$ implies $\overline D \subseteq \overline D_1$.  @geetha290krm

Sorry, there were some  typos.  @JimLin

It’s all right. Thank you for your help to solve my problem. @geetha290krm
